# Creating a JS object

Tags: javascript, object

I am working with the Wordpress REST API to retrieve some tags from a website. Maybe I haven't searched for the correctly on SO, but I am trying to get use my `data` and create my `dataSet` variable. But I am getting an error saying it's not recognizing the `for` loop token. I am quite new to Javascript so I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var pieChart = document.getElementById('pie_chart_1');

req.open("GET", "http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?per_page=10")
req.onload = function() {
  if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
     
    } else {
      console.log("Returning an error");
    }

};

req.onerror = function() {
   console.log("Connection error");
 };

req.send();


var dataSet = [
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    {legendLabel: data[i].name, magnitude:data[i].count, link: "http://example.com/tag" + data[i].slug},
  }
];
```

Comment: declare `i`, something like `for(let i = 0; ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `for` loop inside the square brackets to define an array which is not syntactically correct. Since you are fetching tags using the WordPress REST API the response will be a [JSON object with a `tags` property containing the results](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/read/tags/). It looks like you have a missing `/` in your `link` value as well.

Assuming this value for `data.tags` -

```
[{
  display_name: 'Test Name',
  slug: 'test-name',
}];
```

To properly use a `for` loop for this purpose -

```
const dataSet = [];
const tags = data.tags;
for (let i=0; i<tags.length; i+=1) {
  dataSet.push({
     legendLabel: tags[i].display_name, 
     link: "http://example.com/tag" + tags[i].slug,
  });
}
```

A better way to create an array of JSON objects from your original array of JSON objects is to use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to "map" each element in the first array to a new element in a new array -

```
const dataSet = data.tags.map(function (element) {
  return { 
     legendLabel: element.display_name,
     link: "http://example.com/tag/" + element.slug,
  };
});
```

Taking it further, you can use an arrow function, object parameter deconstruction, explicit return, string patterns, etc for more compact syntax with the same functionality -

```
const dataSet = data.tags.map(({ display_name: displayName, slug }) => ({
  legendLabel: displayName,
  link: `http://example.com/tag/${slug}`,
});
```

Comment: Do correct me if I am wrong, but `data` is using `JSON.parse()` so that would return a JS object. And that is different from an array, right?

Comment: @robot13 `JSON.parse()` can return either a JSON object *or* a JSON array, it depends on the input.

Comment: @robot13 there is no way to know from what you posted - it is whatever the API returns, so it could be either, but if I had to guess from the endpoint name it's either an array or an object with a property that contains an array of results.

Comment: I used the Wordpress REST API

Comment: @robot13 The likely the response is a JSON object with a property called `tags` that contains an array of the results. I will change my answer to reflect this. Please see - https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/read/tags/

Comment: I think it returns something a little different. Because if the link is `http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?per_page-10` and that returns a JSON. Here, this returns a JSON of 10 tags of the wordpress site. Apologies, I should've linked an been more specific. I'll change my question. This is what I am talking about: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: @robot13 it looks like the v2 API uses developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/tags, if you check out the Response Parameters it returns a JSON object with two properties - found for the total number of results and tags which is an array of the current page of results.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in most cases, it is better to use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

In JS there is no for comprehensions so the last block of code could be refactored as follows:

```
const dataSet = data.map(({ name, count, slug }) => ({
  legendLabel: name,
  magnitude: count,
  link: `http://example.com/tag${slug}`
}));
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you process data inside handler function (onload)